# Android Studio unsplit window

Tags: android, user-interface, ide, android-studio

My code window is split by a a 1 pixel wide gray column that i can't seem to remove. It's not the same as splitting Vertically as that produces a second window that i can remove.

I have tried restore default layout to no success. [image: Screenshot depicting split code window]

Comment: I think you have to ask this question in Android Studio FeedBack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right margin of your code and used to control when the IDE will automatically wrap your typing. The right margin can be set in `File->Settings->Code Style->General->Right margin`.

To disable its appearance, `File->Settings->Editor->Appearance->Show right margin`

Comment: Thankyou. Disabling its appearance is sufficient for me.